# Compute average and standard deviation with awk

Tags: awk, standard-deviation

I have a 'file.dat' with  24 (rows) x 16 (columns) data.

I have already tested the following awk script that computes de average of each column.

```
touch aver-std.dat
awk '{   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { sum[i]+= $i } }
END { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++ )  
{ printf "%f \n", sum[i]/NR} }' file.dat >> aver-std.dat
```

The output 'aver-std.dat' has one column with these averages.

Similarly as the average computation 
I would like to compute the standard deviation of each column of the data file 'file.dat' and write it in a second column of the output file. 
Namely I would like an output file with the average in the first column and the standard deviation in the second column.

I have been making different tests, like this one

```
touch aver-std.dat
awk '{   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { sum[i]+= $i }}
END { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++ )  
{std[i] += ($i - sum[i])^2 ; printf "%f %f \n", sum[i]/NR, sqrt(std[i]/(NR-1))}}' file.dat >> aver-std.dat
```

and it writes values in the second column but they are not the correct value of the standard deviation. The computation of the deviation is not right somehow.
I would appreciate very much any help.
Regards

Answer (score 35):

Standard deviation is

```
stdev = sqrt((1/N)*(sum of (value - mean)^2))
```

But there is another form of the formula which does not require you to know the mean beforehand. It is:

```
stdev = sqrt((1/N)*((sum of squares) - (((sum)^2)/N)))
```

(A quick web search for "sum of squares" formula for standard deviation will give you the derivation if you are interested)

To use this formula, you need to keep track of both the sum and the sum of squares of the values. So your awk script will change to:

```
    awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {sum[i] += $i; sumsq[i] += ($i)^2}} 
          END {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
          printf "%f %f \n", sum[i]/NR, sqrt((sumsq[i]-sum[i]^2/NR)/NR)}
         }' file.dat >> aver-std.dat
```

Comment: I only had to add that it was the quasi- standard deviation and has to divide for (NR-1). Regards and thanks.

Comment: @PLM, care to explain your last comment? At the `END` block, `NR` has the total number of rows, which makes this the correct solution.

Comment: @shiri It's the difference between sample standard deviation and population standard deviation. See here for details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction

Answer (score 25):

To simply calculate the population standard deviation of a list of numbers, you can use a command like this:

```
awk '{x+=$0;y+=$0^2}END{print sqrt(y/NR-(x/NR)^2)}'
```

Or this calculates the sample standard deviation:

```
awk '{sum+=$0;a[NR]=$0}END{for(i in a)y+=(a[i]-(sum/NR))^2;print sqrt(y/(NR-1))}'
```

`^` is in POSIX. `**` is supported by `gawk` and `nawk` but not by `mawk`.

Comment: Thanks @nisetama; I used this.  For completeness, the mean can be similarly computed with the one-liner

`awk '{x+=$0}END{print x/NR}'`

Answer (score 4):

Here is some calculation I've made on a grinder data output file for a long soak test which had to be interrupted:

**Standard deviation(biased) + average:**

```
cat <grinder_data_file> | grep -v "1$" | awk -F ', '  '{   sum=sum+$5 ; sumX2+=(($5)^2)} END { printf "Average: %f. Standard Deviation: %f \n", sum/NR, sqrt(sumX2/(NR) - ((sum/NR)^2) )}'
```

**Standard deviation(non-biased) + average:**

```
cat <grinder_data_file>  | grep -v "1$" | awk -F ', '  '{   sum=sum+$5 ; sumX2+=(($5)^2)} END { avg=sum/NR; printf "Average: %f. Standard Deviation: %f \n", avg, sqrt(sumX2/(NR-1) - 2*avg*(sum/(NR-1)) + ((NR*(avg^2))/(NR-1)))}'
```

Comment: There is also another way to calculate the standard deviation taking into account that floating point arithmetics may lead to cancellation.
Check for  B. P. Welford (1962).["Note on a method for calculating corrected sums of squares and products"](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1266577?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents). Technometrics 4(3):419–420

Answer (score -1):

Your script should somehow be in this form instead:

```
awk '{
    sum = 0
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        sum += $i
    }
    avg = sum / NF
    avga[NR] = avg
    sum = 0
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        sum += ($i - avg) ^ 2
    }
    stda[NR] = sqrt(sum / NF)
}

END { for (i = 1; i in stda; ++i) { printf "%f %f \n", avga[i], stda[i] } }' file.dat >> aver-std.dat
```

Comment: This is incorrect for the question asked, as it calculates the std dev for every  **row**, not every column as the OP requested.