# Runtime error (func=(main), adr=5) : Divide by zero - How to fix?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

My shell script is giving the following error: `Runtime error (func=(main), adr=5) : Divide by zero` but I don't see where I could be dividing by zero? I have found other people with similar issues but there solutions are highly specific and can't replicate them within my script. Here is my script:

```
dir=$folder
cd folder

shop1=$1
mean1=4.78
n1=127

shop2=$2
mean2=4.75
n2=324

grep -P -o '(?=<Rating>).*' $hotel1 |
awk '{ sub(/<Overall>/, ""; print }' |
awk '{sum+=$1; sumsq+=$1*$1} END {print sqrt(sumsq/NR - (sum/NR)**2)}'

grep -P -o '(?=<Rating>).*' $hotel2 |
awk '{ sub(/<Overall>/, ""; print }' |
awk '{sum+=$1; sumsq+=$1*$1} END {print sqrt(sumsq/NR - (sum/NR)**2)}'

md=0.03
d1=0.003
d2=0.0038
d1d2=$(echo "d1 + d2" | bc)
sq=0.069
tstat=$(echo "md / sq" | bc)
```

My script basically will eventually calculate the t-statistic from my two data files, to do this it first calculates the standard deviation of each file. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You don't have to mix grep and awk like that.  One precious awk can rule them all.

Comment: I pass these inputs through in the command line './myscript.sh shop_2344.dat shop_4121.dat'

Comment: I don't think this will be the issue as I get a numerical output from these two parts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not `awk`, here is the problem

```
tstat=$(echo "md / sq" | bc)
```

you have to refer to bash variables with `$` prefix.

Needless to say, all of your script can be simplified into one `awk`

Comment: Doesn't this also round the result to an integer?  (Probably not good for a _t_-value.)

Comment: So tstat=$(echo "$md / $sq" | bc) ? If thats the case then wouldn't I need to change the d1d2 line aswell

Comment: Just write the whole thing in awk and you don't have to worry about stuff like this.  Sometimes simplicity wins.

Comment: @John Smith, for both, it's consistent. For summation it won't fail but won't give the result you want either.

Comment: I know but I don't know how to :p

Comment: I think I wrote a similar code here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35628103/how-do-i-calculate-the-standard-deviation-in-my-shell-script/35629989#35629989  Isn't it the same thing?

Comment: Why would my output when I 'echo $tstat' be 0? I did the math and it should be 0.027789?

Comment: To get floating point result use `bc -l`, otherwise it's rounded to int.