# bash: calculation of the RMSD from the dataset

Tags: bash, awk, statistics

I have a my_file.xvg contained 240 lines with the numbers arranged in the following format:

```
    5.4
    5.1
    5.2
    5.4
    5.4
    4.9
    5.0
    5.2
....
    4.9
```

Using awk I have already calculated the mean value of these data and store it as a "mean" variable in the bash script:

```
mean=$(awk '{sum+=$1}END{printf "%.1f", sum/NR}' my_file.xvg)
```

How could I calculate RMSD of these numbers (to determine error of the mean for instance) and store it as the another variable?

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786073/compute-average-and-standard-deviation-with-awk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the value of the mean is saved in the variable a very similar approach can be used for the RMSD. As you seem to prefer awk, see the following:

```
rmsd=$(awk -v mean=$mean '{++n;sum+=($NF-mean)^2} END{if(n) print sqrt(sum/n)}' my_file.xvg)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine!  how it could be possible to round the rmsd value to the second number after . inside the awk expression ? For instance now the rmsd may be around 0.55715 calculated from the mean=3.7. I need rmsd = 0.56 in that case ...

Comment: as in your example use `printf`:   `awk -v mean=$mean '{++n;sum+=($NF-mean)^2} END{if(n) printf "%.2f", sqrt(sum/n)}' test.txt`

Answer (score 1):

No need to run `awk` script twice, you can calculate the stats in one go

```
$ read -r mean std < <(awk '{s+=$1;ss+=$1^2} END{printf "%.2f %.2f",m=s/NR,sqrt(ss/NR-m^2)}' file)

$ echo $mean $std
5.20 0.18
```

Comment: super method! Does it mean that read -r mean std create on the fly two variables from AWK that will be further used in the bash script ?

Comment: also could you precise why you used different formula for calculation of the mean (which however gives very closed results)?   thank ++

Comment: It's the same formula. Do you mean 2 decimal points instead of 1?

Comment: This code actually uses the full precision of the numbers, so accuracy will be higher.  You can truncate while printing. Truncation of the mean for std computation is not advised.